# Remove duplicated text using jquery

Tags: jquery

say I have the following

```
 <h3>This is my heading</h3>
 <p>This is my headingAnd this is part of a paragraph</p>
```

I want to end up with the following

```
 <h3>This is my heading</h3>
 <p>And this is part of a paragraph...</p>
```

I found this code

```
   $(function() {
   var seen = {};
    $('p, h3').each(function() {
    var txt = $(this).text();
     if (seen[txt])
     $(this).remove();
   else
     seen[txt] = true;
  });
});
```

but because there are two words joined in the paragraph it won't work. The data is being pulled dynamically from a rss feed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you DOM structure remain as you stated above then following will work for you:

```
$('p').text(function(index, oldText) {
  return oldText.replace($(this).prev('h1').text(), '');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hrAyx/)**

#### According to your comment

```
<div id="youtube">
    <section>
        <h3>Launch of the Active Living impact checklist</h3>
        <p>Launch of the Active Living impact checklistFrom test</p>
        <a target="_blank" href="#"> watch video</a> <br>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h3>Enterprise Computing Conference</h3>
        <p>Enterprise Computing ConferenceWorld leaders in enterprise computing attended a two</p>
        <a target="_blank" href="#"> watch video</a> <br>
    </section>
</div>

$('p').text(function(index, oldText) {
  return oldText.replace($(this).prev('h3').text(), '');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4vKsg/1/)**

Comment: Thanks, I should have mentioned that there are more than one section that has duplication

Comment: @NickP Doesn't matter if it has more section, just place evety `h1` before `p` and it will work.

Comment: Thank you thecodeparadox it works exactly like I wanted it to.

Answer (score 0):

```
var header = ​$('h1').​​​​text();
var body = $('p').text();

if (body.indexOf(header) >= 0) {
    $('p').text(body.replace(header, ''));
}
```

​
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eNSDJ/)